# Why isn't this simple Ruby code working in HAML?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

If I run this simple Ruby code regularly, it works fine:

```
class String
  def add_two
    self + "2"
  end
end
puts "hello".add_two
```

It prints "hello2" as it should. But this fails:

```
:ruby
  class String
    def add_two
      self + "2"
    end
  end
  puts "hello".add_two
```

This code produces an error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `add_two' for "hello":String
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

(Not sure if it matters, but I'm using HAML with Sinatra, which is running on Apache with the Passenger module.)

Comment: Can you try adding `puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"` before `puts "hello".add_two" `

Comment: Are you following the MVC architecture? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I feel like you really shouldnt be monkey-patching String in a view

Comment: you're doing it wrong, really ;)

Comment: @AJcodez and others: I know this is bad practice, and I won't be doing this in actual programs, but I still want to understand why this doesn't work. What makes "monkey-patching" String special enough that it should not work in HAML?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan If I add that, it doesn't change anything. By the way, I got the wrong error earlier and have updated the error now in the question.

Comment: I think you should try this using [Haml in the console](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_module) and remove Sinatra from the equation e.g. (your Haml is in the string `s`) `engine = Haml::Engine.new s; engine.render; #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'add_two' for "hello":String`. Maybe it's something to do with Tilt and not Haml, so try it with [slim](http://slim-lang.com/) and [something else that uses Tilt](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Available%20Template%20Languages) too.

Comment: My guess would be it wraps all the Ruby in the Haml in an anonymous module, much like [Kernel#load](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load) and this would prevent you opening `String` in this way, but that's just my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that String is in another namespace and therefor another class.

What happens with that?

```
class ::String
```

Comment: For reference, this doesn't work in a Rails view, but who cares since it works in Sinatra and solves the question: +1.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code as is into one of my Haml views in a Rails app and I got a different error to you:

```
SyntaxError at /
class definition in method body
```

So I wondered whether it was [Haml's `:ruby` filter](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-filter) that was complaining, but since it "Parses the filtered text with the normal Ruby interpreter", it seemed unlikely.  So, I searched for more info about the error and found references (see below) that led me to this, which works (but, really, should never be used):

```
:ruby
  String.module_eval do
    def add_two
      self + "2"
    end
  end
  puts "hello".add_two
```

References:

- [Class inside a Method Body](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/199339)
- [Class (Re)definition in Method Body](http://blog.choonkeat.com/weblog/2007/02/class-redefinit.html)